# Relational data in Weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have data in this format: I have tuples of the amount of data and the processing time per function. I want to do a classification by the "class" attribute

Here is a sample:

```
Amount-F1 Time-F1 Amount-F2 Time-F2 [...] Class
50         10      20        10            1
20         2       100       20            3
...
```

How should I build the arff file? Should I use the relational attribute for the (Ammount,Time) tuples or should I use "regular" attributes?

**Can you make me a sample arff file for my example please?**

Thank you

Comment: What about importing the data as a simple CSV datafile? Weka can import that. And don't use minus signs in column names, better use underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEKA can also work with csv files. But if you want to use arff-format, WEKA does support:
[weka.core.converters.ArffSaver / weka.core.converters.CSVLoader](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF)

You could *split each tuple* into *2 separate features*:

```
@RELATION yourTable

@ATTRIBUTE Amount-F1 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Time-F1 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Amount-F2 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Time-F2 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Amount-F3 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE Time-F3 NUMERIC
...
@ATTRIBUTE Class {1,2,3} % your class labels

@DATA
50, 10, 20, 10, 1
20, 2, 100, 20, 3
...
```

or use an **Aggregation** of **Time** and **Amount**:

*Amount-F1* and *Time-F1* as *F1*:

```
@RELATION yourTable

@ATTRIBUTE F1 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE F2 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE F3 NUMERIC
...
@ATTRIBUTE Class {1,2,3} % your class labels

@DATA
5, 2, 1    % 50/10, 20/10, 1
10, 5, 3   % 20/2, 100/20, 3
...
```

Depending on the use-case, generally I would prefer the second option.